# AVAudiorecorder PCM format

Tags: objective-c

I use the AVAudiorecorder to write a apps for recording the sound. In the audio setting, i change the input signal as a PCM format.

```
NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:32] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey]; 
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
```

I want to extract the PCM, how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more clear as to what do you mean by "extract the PCM". The AVAudioRecoder saves the recorded file in the path you specify while initializing the recorder object. 
Perhaps you could use NSData and NSFileHandle to get the raw bit stream from this file to "extract the PCM".

Answer (score 0):

One approach: Locate the recorded file then use `ExtAudioFile*` or `AudioFile*` APIs to read the samples. See `AudioFileReadPackets` and/or `ExtAudioFileRead` for related APIs and sample code.